# Command exec android

Tags: android, exec

to the screen capture I use this command, on the virtual emulator it works well and makes the screen capture but on my phone (galaxy gio) does not work, I will not understand what the problem please help me thank you

```
Process sh;
sh = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("adb shell screencap -p /sdcard/screen.png");
```

Comment: Is your phone(galaxy gio) rooted?

Comment: yes,my phone is rooted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
Process sh = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su", null,null);
OutputStream  os = sh.getOutputStream();
os.write(("/system/bin/screencap -p " + "/sdcard/img.png").getBytes("ASCII"));
os.flush();
os.close();
sh.waitFor();
```

if not then

You can try the following library: http://code.google.com/p/android-screenshot-library/ Android Screenshot Library (ASL) enables to programmatically capture screenshots from Android devices without requirement of having root access privileges.

Comment: I try with this library but it shows me this message "Native Service not found."

Comment: this code is running on tablet version 4 but not for version 2 so this is a problem version of android, thank you